# Using Fastlane to automate apk upload

Tags: android, rubygems, fastlane

I have installed ruby,DevKit and Fastlane to automate the apk upload to Google play store.

But whenever I try to execute fastlane command it gives me following error

```
C:\Users\testuser>fastlane --version
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
: cannot load such file -- pty (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-1.48.0/lib/fastlane
/actions/actions_helper.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-1.48.0/lib/fastlane
.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-1.48.0/bin/fastlane
:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/fastlane:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/fastlane:23:in `<main>'

C:\Users\testuser>
```

Am i missing something here??

Answer (score 0):

Fastlane is trying to load `pty` but this gem is not available for Windows yet, you can read these Github issues for more information:

1. [Issue 16](https://github.com/fastlane-old/supply/issues/16)
2. [Issue 2082](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/2082)

Answer (score 0):

Windows is not an officially supported platform for fastlane right now, sorry!

While Ruby does run on Windows, some of its classes and methods are not compatible with Windows, and fastlane depends on `PTY` which is one of those incompatible classes.